# Image is not saving after updating, in c# using FileStream or Simple Bitmap

Tags: c#, gdi+, bit-manipulation

I am working for a utility in desktop application, related to some graphics work.

I have to load small thumbnails and full sized bitmap.I am doing this using this code.

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream("myphoto.jpg", FileMode.Open);
 Image imgPhoto = Image.FromStream(fs);
 fs.Close();
 PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
 p.Name = "p1";
 p.Image = imgPhoto;
 flowPanel.Controls.Add(p);
 //---- 
 FileStream fs = new FileStream("myphoto_thumb.jpg", FileMode.Open);
 Image img = Image.FromStream(fs);
 fs.Close();
 Button b_thumb = new Button();
 b_thumb.Name = "thumb1";
 b_thumb.BackgroundImage = img;
 flowBottom.Controls.Add(b_thumb);
```

After this, i need to add some effects on image of this picturebox.When i add some effect to main (big) image in picturebox, i also add the same effect in botton background image.When i save this thumbnail image to existing thumbnail image it is saving, but when i save the big image from picturebox on the existing file "myphoto.jpg", it gives me error like FILE IS BEING USED BY ANOTHER PROCESS

```
//---- Add some Effects to image of Picturebox ---- //
PictureBox tempPic = flowPanel.Controls["p1"];
tempPic.Image.Save("myphoto.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I have found many solutions on google and on stackoverflow but could not find helpful.
If any good solution, plz help.
May be its very simple but i have tried more than 10 hours but failed.

Comment: what is this gdi+? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx states this is legacy api for c/c++ programmers, you write c# code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't close the FileStream you open. I always wrap this kind of stuff in a `using` construction, so it automatically gets destructed, thus closes:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("myphoto.jpg", FileMode.Open)) {
  // Do stuff
}

tempPic.Image.Save("myphoto.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Doesn't the `fs.close()` close the stream?

Comment: I'm sorry... I totally missed that line. So mine is not really an answer to your problem. Still, I recommend the `using` construction, as it makes sure stuff gets cleaned up, even on exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your filestream to read only:

```
fs = New System.IO.FileStream("myphoto.jpg", 
     IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
```

This is Microsoft's recommendation, targeted at users who try Image.FromFile and it locks the file: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309482